# Calculate laplacian on numpy masked array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy

I have a numpy masked array and I want to calculate the Laplacian then variance of the masked array. I can easily do this for a unmasked/normal array but don't know how to do this for a masked one.

Can you inform me of a way I can calculate the laplacian on a masked numpy array? Maybe scipy or another library has a way to do it?

The below code code is for when I calculate the laplacian then variance for a normal array:

```
roi1_var = cv2.Laplacian(sample1,cv2.CV_64F).var()
roi2_var = cv2.Laplacian(sample2,cv2.CV_64F).var()
var_diff = abs(roi1_var - roi2_var)
```

Heres my masked array that I need to calculate the laplacian then variance on:

```
mask = np.ones((src.shape[0], src.shape[1], 3), dtype='uint8')
cv2.drawContours(mask, [np.array(poly)], -1, (0,0,0), -1)
msrc = np.ma.array(src, mask=mask)

# The following will not consider the mask will it?
variance = cv2.Laplacian(msrc ,cv2.CV_64F).var()
```

Comment: Only `np.ma` functions, and functions that delegate to the ma  array methods, will pay attention to the mask.  `cv2` knows nothing about the mask.  How do you want the mask to affect the calculation?

Comment: Typically masked calculations compress the data (remove the masked values), or fill the masked values with a neutral value.